# how to use two different controllers in the same page jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I m using spring mvc 3 and jsp for interfaces , the problem that i have one page jsp which contains 3 diffrenets controllers like this :
 the first:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping ("/contrats")
public class ContratController {
```

the sd:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/contratgaranties")

public class ContratGarantieController {
```

and

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/souscripteurs")
public class SouscripteurController {
```

i would like to maintain 3 datatables in the same page jsp without any one of this datatables will be empty like now.

plz help thx :))

Comment: Can you give an example of how it's used in the jsp?

Comment: Questions isn't clear enough please elaborate more.

Answer (score 0):

Use an asynchronous request on the client and use `@ResponseBody` annotation type on your controller method returns types.

Answer (score 0):

However the question is not clear, I think I have solved the same issue using REST and ajax calls for each data table,my solution was using jqgrid and it is calling REST services for retrieve and edit data, so first you have to implement 3 REST services then, you have to do 3 data tables to call these REST services.